# Double cover of symplectic groups

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-topology, geometric-group-theory

What is the normal definition of double cover of Symplectic group? I couldn't find a simple and understandable definition

Comment: Are you asking about the definition of a double cover of a group, in particular, the symplectic group, or are you asking about the definition of the [Metaplectic group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaplectic_group)?

Comment: for undrestanding the definition of  Metaplectic group, I need the definition of double covering of a group

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $G,H$ are groups then $H$ is a double cover of $G$ iff $H$ has a normal subgroup $K$ of order 2 such that $K \leq [H,H] \cap Z(H)$ and $H/K \cong G$.

In other words, $H$ has an element $z$ that (1) commutes with every element of $H$, (2) can be written as a product of commutators $z=\left(h_1^{-1} h_2^{-1} h_1 h_2\right)\cdots\left(h_{2n-1}^{-1} h_{2n}^{-1} h_{2n-1}h_{2n}\right)$, (3) $z$ has order 2, and (4) if we ignore $z$, then we just get $G \cong H/\langle z\rangle$.

A triple cover is defined similarly, except $K$ has order 3.

A double cover has the neat property that every element of $G$ has two ghosts in $H$, one light and one dark. If Scott is an element of $H$, then there is always Nega-Scott in $H$ as well. In representations of $G$, both Scott and Nega-Scott have the same action and character, but the representations of $H$ (called projective representations of $G$) reveal the true character, with the value of Nega-Scott being the negative of the value of Scott.

Strictly, I think I may need that $Z(G)$ is finite of odd order for this dichotomy to hold, and I usually consider finite groups, so my apologies if an infinite evil representation interferes.

Comment: The condition that $K\leq Z(H)$ is not really needed, as $K$ has order $2$ and is normal (but it is of course needed once you go to triple cover). Is it obvious that the element can be written as a commutator, rather than as a product of commutators?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: product of commutators in general, sorry.I'll fix.

Comment: Ahh, so I wasn't overlooking something. Good.

Comment: I left in the condition (1) just because it doesn't hurt, is needed for the general definition of cover, and is important for the ghost business.